# "Piecewise Linear" Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm interested in the following "piecewise-linear" ordinary differential equation:
$$
\ddot{x}(t) = \begin{cases}
-k_+ x(t) - b_+ \dot x(t) + u(t) & x(t) \geq 0\\
-k_- x(t) - b_- \dot x(t) + u(t) & x(t) < 0,
\end{cases}
\quad x(0) = x_0, \quad \dot x(0) = \dot x_0,
$$
where we are given some (smooth) forcing function $u(t)$ and positive coefficients $k_{\pm}$ and $b_{\pm}$.  If you prefer, I have step-function coefficients $k(x)$ and $b(x)$, and my equation is of the form
$$
\ddot{x}(t) = -k(x)x(t) - b(x) x(t) + u(t).
$$
Ultimately, I'd like to be able to show that for two solutions $x_1,x_2$, we have $\frac d{dt}|x_1(t) - x_2(t)| < 0$. The fact that this is not simply a linear differential equation makes this difficult.

One approach to the problem is to solve the (countably many) initial value problems, where we switch from one ODE to the other at each time at which we have $x(t) = 0$, and the "final values" for the trajectory over $[0,t]$ serve as the "initial values" for the next trajectory.

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Does this fall into any well-known class of problems? I would appreciate any ideas and any helpful keywords to search or resources to look for.

Comment: Filippov's ODE? Filippov's solution?

Comment: @pluton Interesting. It's certainly an applicable framework but from the few references I found I don't see how to get the kind of result I'm looking for